# Python 3.7 os module "Windows cannot find image.png"

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have tried to display an image using the os module, but every time I run the program This error appears along with the cmd window in the background:

*Windows cannot find 'image.png'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again*

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import os

cho = input("> ")
if cho == "y":
    os.system('start image.png')
```

I really don't know what to do anymore. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the actual filename of the image? Is it located in the same folder as the script?

Comment: You should be using `os.startfile('image.png')` instead of `os.system`. It probably won't resolve the fact that the relative filename isn't found in the current working directory, which probably is not what you expect it to be, but at least it's an API call in the current process instead of spawing a child cmd.exe process to do the work.

Comment: BTW, it's a console window, not a CMD window. cmd.exe is a command-line interface (CLI) shell based on standard I/O, which, as a console application, by default connects to either an inherited console session or a new console session for its standard I/O files. python.exe is no different from cmd.exe in this regard. Run python.exe from the desktop GUI shell, and you'll get a console window for a new console session, which has nothing to do with cmd.exe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming `image.png` and your python file are in the same folder, this behavior is weird.
You can try as follows:

```py
import os

image_path = r"image.png" # if both are in same directory
# image_path = r"<absolute_path>" works in any case
# the r before the string (path) makes python treat it as raw string (escape special characters)

os.system(image_path)
# os.system('start ' + image_path)
```

Comment: Thx. Never thought of putting it in same folder!

Comment: The directory of the script is not generally the current directory. The process can be created with any arbitrary working directory. You don't control this. If the file is in the script directory, use `image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'image.png')`.